# Select a number randomly from 1 to 99

Tags: c#, .net, random

I want to select a random number from `1` to `99`. And then select the number again but this time discard the previous number. Can someone help me.

Comment: discard the previous number means do you want to generate unique number each time?

Comment: yes the no should be selected from rest of the numbers.

Comment: this i want to code a game called Housie

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();
private Random rnd = new Random();

public int GetRandomInt()
{
    var index = rnd.Next(0, numbers.Length);
    var number = numbers[index];
    numbers.RemoveAt(index);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, but the sequence requires a range from 1 to 99: the zero should be avoided.

Comment: i am writing this code for a generate button. so wen every time i click generate it will generate unique number right?????

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var numbers = new Stack<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 99).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
```

You effectively are randomizing the list of numbers and then adding them to a stack. Now you just have to do this to get each number:

```
var next = numbers.Pop()
```

You stop when `numbers.Count == 0`. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the revised version of Khanh TO, because it is not correct:

```
        List<int> usedNumbers = new List<int>();

        Random rand = new Random(new object().GetHashCode());
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                number = 1 + rand.Next(0, 99);
            } while (usedNumbers.Contains(number));
            usedNumbers.Add(number);
        }
```

Comment: this code will give me 1 random no right.
when i have to find next no randomly then also i have to use the same code?????

Comment: Not sure to understand. The above code generates a list of numbers, as you ask. The list contains *already* the sequence of numbers that will be extracted. You don't have to re-run the code, unless you want to start the game again.
However, the Enigmativity's solution is the most elegant. The MarcinJuraszek's one is also valuable. I posted this one just because the original code was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it with arrays.

Whenever you create a random number just put on the array. so next time check if the number is already generated by checking in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            IList<int> arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 99).ToList();
            int randNum;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            randNum = rnd.Next(1, arr.Count());
            MessageBox.Show(randNum.ToString());
            arr = arr.Where(x => x != randNum).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I go for the shortest code, without a nested loop, or removing list elements.

### Code 1

```
class Program
{
    static Random rnd=new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list=new SortedDictionary<double, int>();
        // Fill list
        for (int i=1; i<=99; i++)
        {
            list.Add(rnd.NextDouble(), i);
        }
        // List Automatically random
        var random_int=list.Values.ToArray();
        // random_int = {45, 7, 72, .. }
    }
}
```

### Code 2

```
class Program
{
    static Random rnd=new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list=new int[99];
        // Fill list
        for (int i=1; i<=99; i++)
        {
            list[i-1]=i;
        }
        Comparison<int> any=(x, y) =>
        {
            var z=2*rnd.NextDouble()-1;
            return z.CompareTo(0);
        };
        // Randomize List
        Array.Sort(list, any);
        // list = { 49, 59, 21, 7, 18 ...}
    }
}
```